# Como buscar e salvar um único campo?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update

Como posso buscar um único campo da tabela altera-lo e salvar esse campo sem que tenha que buscar todos os campos da tabela?

O motivo para isso é simples, tenho algumas tabelas que tem mais de 30 colunas e isso tem um custo alto de processamento na aplicação quando as vezes é atualizado apenas um campo dessa tabela, como no exemplo abaixo, tenho a tabela Cidades e só preciso alterar o nome da cidade, como poderia buscar e alterar somente o campo Nome?

**Obs**; estou usando [system.data.linq.datacontext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) meu context é assim.

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Tabela_ScanImagen> Tabela_ScanImagens
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Tabela_ScanImagen>();
    }
}
```

---

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Tabela_ScanImagens")]
public partial class Tabela_ScanImagen : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);  
    private double _Imagem; 
    private string _Path;   
    private System.Nullable<double> _Cliente;   
    private System.Nullable<double> _Orcamento; 
    private System.Nullable<double> _Documento; 
    private System.Nullable<double> _Alteracao; 
    private System.Nullable<double> _Sinistro;  
    private System.Nullable<double> _Seguradora;    
    private System.Nullable<double> _Divisao;   
    private string _Descricao;
}
```

Tentei fazer usando o pacote EntityFramework.Extended, porem ele só aceita o context sendo `System.Data.Entity` **DbContext**

```
public void Salvar()
    {
        using (var dm = new DmContext())
        {
            var _descricao = dm.Tabela_ScanImagens
                 .Where(c => c.Imagem == 6)
                 .Select(c => c.Descricao)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

            dm.Tabela_ScanImagens.Update(c => new Tabela_ScanImagen { Descricao = "teste" });

            dm.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Dessa forma ele me retorna o seguinte erro.

> The query must be of type ObjectQuery or DbQuery. Nome do parâmetro:
>   source

Comment: Então você pode utilizar o método db.ExecuteCommand() para fazer o update de apenas um campo. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Amigo, essas são umas das perdas que temos com ORMs. Nem todos implementam atualizações parciais, ou recuperação parcial dos dados do servidor, pois isso iria dificultar a "transparência" com que se deseja lidar com objetos mapeados. Contudo, isso está realmente prejudicando a performance do seu sistema, ou você está tentando otimizar antes de instrumentalizar um teste de performance usando uma ferramenta específica para profiling da aplicação? Se realmente se mostrar um gargalo, faça chamadas diretas ao SGBD, podendo, inclusive, embutir o UPDATE com SELECT em uma única chamada. Não se engesse

Comment: Estou aceitando a resposta abaixo, porem ela não atendeu o que realmente queria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso:

#### 1. Usando o pacote [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Instale o pacote

> PM > Install-Package EntityFramework.Extended

Aí, você pode fazer o seguinte

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;

public void Salvar()
{
    using (var ctx = new ExemplosEntities())
    {
        ctx.Cidades.Where(c => c.IdCidade == 1)
                   .Update(c => new Cidade { Nome = "São Carlos" });

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

#### 2. Usando [`ExecuteCommand()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (var ctx = new ExemplosEntities()) 
{ 
    var command = "UPDATE dbo.ScanImagens SET Descricao = 'Teste' WHERE Id = 1";
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command); 
}
```

[Mais exemplos aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)

#### 3. Usando a propriedade `IsModified`

É possível também "avisar" ao contexto que nem todas as propriedades foram modificadas, desta forma.

```
using (var dm = new DmContext())
{
    var excluded = new [] { "Id", "Nome", "Etc" };
    // array com as propriedades não modificadas

    var entry = dm.Entry(obj);
    foreach (var name in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Except(excluded))
    {
        entry.Property(name).IsModified = true;
    }           

    dm.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void Salvar()
   {
     using (var ctx = new ExemplosEntities())
       {

          var Cidade = ctx.Cidade.First(c => c.IdCidade == 1);

          Cidade.Nome = "São Carlos";

          ctx.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
```

verifique nisto:

`var Cidade = ctx.Cidade.First(c => c.IdCidade == 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Honestamente eu prefiro a resposta do @jbueno, que utiliza `EntityFramework.Extended`.

Mas como você utiliza `system.data.linq.datacontext` não sei se ela se aplica.  Conforme falei nos cometários, você pode utilizar uma procedure ou executar um comando sql pelo DbContext. Dessa forma você não precisa realizar nenhuma consulta extra ao db para alterar as colunas necessárias.

**É necessário validar as strings que serão concatenadas ao comando SQL, para evitar injeções de código como SQL Injection.**

Ex.

```
public int AlterarDescricao(string novaDescricao)
{
    int linhasAfetadas = 0;
    //Crie um método para validar a string novaDescricao contra possível injeções de código.
    var stringValidadaContraSqlInjection = ValidarInput(novaDescricao);
    using (var dm = new DmContext())
    {
        linhasAfetadas = dm.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Tabela_ScanImagen SET Descricao = {0} WHERE Imagem  = 6", stringValidadaContraSqlInjection );
    }
    return linhasAfetadas;
}
```

Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Não é meu objetivo usar esse tipo de comando.