# Como é montado a query gerada no Linq quando fazemos UPDATE?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Como é montado a query gerada no Linq quando fazemos UPDATE?

```
using ColWebDBContext.DBase.Banco;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Linq;

namespace DBContext
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ctx = new dbContext())
            {
                var Produto = ctx.Tabela_Produtos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Produto == 1);
                Produto.Nome = "Bombril";
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No exemplo a cima, eu faço a busca de todas as colunas do objeto(Tabela_Produtos), altero o campo **Nome** e mando o *Context* salvar, se eu estivesse fazendo a query de update com a sintaxe do sql isso seria assim;

```
update Tabela_Produtos
set Nome = 'Bombril'
where Produto = 1;
```

Minhas duvidas são;

1. O **Context** tem alguma forma para gerar a mesma sintaxe?
2. Existe alguma forma de ver a query que está sendo enviada para o
   banco nesse caso?

*A pergunta a baixo é a mais critica e a que mais tenho interesse em saber.*

3. Como é feito pelo **Context** para que ele saiba que somente a coluna
   **Nome** sofreu alteração?

Comment: a pergunta 2 é um complemento da 1, certo?

Comment: Praticamente só preciso saber como ver essa query, alguma forma de capturar ela. não tem muita relação entre a 1 e a 2. a primeira quero saber como é gerada e a segunda quero saber se tem como eu captura-la, copiar. entendendo esse processo ira me ajudar a solucionar [esse outro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160668/como-buscar-e-salvar-um-%C3%BAnico-campo)

Comment: Está utilizando o SQL Server?

Comment: @Randrade, exato, não sei se tem alguma diferença entre bancos.

Comment: tem ferramentas que o SQL Possui exatamente para ajudar com isso. Estarei elaborando uma resposta mais detalhada aqui.

Comment: @Randrade, mas isso é através do banco? porque a 2 pergunta pode até ser, mas a 1 e a 3 gostaria de sabe as (propriedades , métodos ) usados pelo Context,

Comment: Essa pergunta não é duplicada [desta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160668/18246)?

Comment: @jbueno, não... tem o mesmo objetivo, mas e outra coisa , [falei aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162071/como-%C3%A9-montado-a-query-gerada-no-linq-quando-fazemos-update?noredirect=1#comment333215_162071)

Comment: Que confusão...

Comment: @jbueno, porque ? não esta clara a pergunta? se eu editasse a outra com isso a mais iria se torna muito grande.

Comment: @jbueno, o que eu pensei para solucionar o outro caso foi o seguinte, se eu soube como é feito no context para ele só alterar um determinado campo então tem a possibilidade de eu dizer quais campos eu quero alterar com isso eu poderia fazer o select somente dos campos que eu quero e dizer que quais quero alterar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o contexto (`DbContext`) funciona quando chamo uma entidade por `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Find(value)`, ou seja, trago um registro para alteração:

***Model:***

```
[Table("Credit")]
public class Credit
{
    public Credit()
    {
    }
    public Credit(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }
    public Credit(int id, string description)
    {
        Id = id;
        Description = description;
    }

    [Key()]  
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int Lines { get; set; }
}
```

***Contexto (DbContext):***

```
public class Database  : DbContext
{
    public Database()
        :base(@"Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=dbtest;User Id=sa;Password=senha;")
    {
       Database.Initialize(false);
    }

    public DbSet<Credit> Credit { get; set; }    
}
```

***Executando operações:***

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Database db = new Database())
        {
            db.Database.Log = ca => WriteLog(ca);

            int value = 1;
            Credit cr = db.Credit.Find(value);
            cr.Lines = cr.Lines + 1;
            db.SaveChanges();

        }



        System.Console.WriteLine("Pression <Enter> ...");
    }

    public static void WriteLog(string c)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

No código acima é utilizado a auditoria basica no qual mostra quais `SQL` estão sendo geradas, no caso exemplo são duas um `Select` e um `Update`, sendo um atualização somente daquilo que foi modificado, como demostrado no `debug` logo abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, concluisse que é feito o `update` somente da propriedade que foi alterada.

> 1 - O Context tem alguma forma para gerar a mesma sintaxe?

Sim ele gera a mesma sintaxe, fazendo atualizações somente das propriedades que foram alteradas.

> 2 - Existe alguma forma de ver a query que está sendo enviada para o banco nesse caso?

Sim exite, `db.Database.Log` trará as `SQL` geradas pelo contexto.

```
using (Database db = new Database())
{
     db.Database.Log = ca => WriteLog(ca);
```

Pode ser utilizado também na janela de `Debug Trace`:

```
db.Database.Log = ca => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ca);
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> 3 - Como é feito pelo Context para que ele saiba que somente a coluna Nome sofreu alteração?

```
Credit cr = db.Credit.Find(value);
cr.Lines = cr.Lines + 1;
db.Entry(cr).Property(x => x.Lines).IsModified
```

Isso demostra `db.Entry(cr).Property(x => x.Lines).IsModified` se a propriedade sofreu alguma alteração, o **Contexto** se basea na resposta verdade (`true`) e o código se encarrega de fazer a alteração somente daquilo que está modificado como `true`.

Não existe nada implementado para verificar quais campos estão modificados de uma só vez, mas, pode ser feito facilmente por um método de extensão, para dizer quais campos sofreram mudanças e quais não sofreram:

```
public static class MethodsUpdate
{
    public static Dictionary<string, bool> GetUpdatePropertyNames<T>(this DbEntityEntry<T> entry)
        where T: class, new()
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> entryUpdate =
            new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        foreach (string name in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            entryUpdate.Add(name, entry.Property(name).IsModified);
        }
        return entryUpdate;
    }
}

Dictionary<string, bool> propertyChanges = db.Entry(cr).GetUpdatePropertyNames();
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa caso especifico ainda não foi aplicado a alteração no banco, somente em seu contexto.

Referencias:

- [Entity Framework 6 – Gerando Log dos comandos SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn479056.aspx)
- [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations With Entity Framework 6.0](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ff2f08/logging-and-intercepting-database-operations-with-entity-fra/)
- [Update only modified fields in Entity Framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37304/update-only-modified-fields-in-entity-framework)
- [How can I log the generated SQL from DbContext.SaveChanges() in my Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20757916/6797930)
- [Microsoft Developer Network - DbEntityEntry Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Entity Framework Tutorial - DBEntityEntry Class](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbentityentry.aspx)
- [Get Table Name From DbEntityEntry (Code-First)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543009/6797930)
- [Get Primary Key of DBEntityEntry when Adding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25921320/6797930)
- [Mocking or faking DbEntityEntry or creating a new DbEntityEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5036364/6797930)

Comment: Eu acho que o método `WriteLog` só vai funcionar em `ConsoleApplications`, não?

Comment: @MarllonNasser, nesse exemplo sim, mas, a necessidade é mesmo de teste, mas, você pode usar em qualquer lugar gerando `logs` e isso é bem util, não se limita somente em `Console Application`. Pode ser utilizado isso de várias formas !!!

Comment: o ConsoleApplications não é um problema para mim.

Comment: Não entendi @GOKUSSJGod? desculpas!

Comment: Ele quis dizer que pode utilizar a solução proposta, mesmo que seja "somente" no `ConsoleApplication`. Eu pensei que sua aplicação fosse web, @GOKUSSJGod.

Comment: Sobre os camentarios acima, o ConsoleApplications não é problema, só não tem explicação para o número 3. minha aplicação é web sim... mas posso mudar isso para um campo de text da aplicação.

Comment: Opa @GOKUSSJGod já vou postar !!!

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod eu fiz uma edição espero ter ajudado.

Comment: não esta bem explicado, mas as funções passadas serviram o proposito.

Comment: O que eu posso melhorar @GOKUSSJGod por favor pode dizer?

Comment: bela implementação do `GetUpdatePropertyNames`!! `+1`

Comment: Vlw @MarllonNasser

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod se eu puder melhorar mais, com alguma dica sua, o outro duvida, você pode dizer sem problemas, e fico no aguardo, eu vou dar uma saída na volta se eu puder ajudar.

Comment: Umas referências já seria ótimo.

Answer (score 5):

1. O **Context** tem alguma forma para gerar a mesma sintaxe?

Não sei, mas acho que não... perde o sentido a utilização do `entity` quando você quer fazer "coisas" de `ADO.NET`.

2. Existe alguma forma de ver a query que está sendo enviada para o banco nesse caso?

Sim. Você pode criar seu próprio `logger` ou criar uma simples extensão:

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static string TraceSql<T>(this IQueryable<T> t)
    {
        var sql = "";
        ObjectQuery<T> oqt = t as ObjectQuery<T>;

        if (oqt != null)
            sql = oqt.ToTraceString();

        return sql;
    }
}
```

Ou:

```
ctx.Database.Log = x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);
```

3. Como é feito pelo **Context** para que ele saiba que somente a coluna
   **Nome** sofreu alteração?

Através do [GetModifiedMembers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534359(v=vs.110).aspx) ou através de uma pequena implementação:

```
using (var ctx = new dbContext())
{
    var Produto = (from p in ctx.Produto
                            where p.Produto == 1
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
    Produto.Nome = "Bombril";

    QueryHelper<Product>.Log(db, Produto);//seu logger

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}


public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static void Log<T>(DataContext dataContext, T entidade) where T : Class
    {
        foreach(var propriedadeModificada in dataContext.GetTable<T>().GetModifiedMembers(entidade))
        {
            var valorAtual = propriedadeModificada.CurrentValue;
            var valorOriginal = propriedadeModificada.OriginalValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: na 2, como eu chamaria esse método? através do Produto.TraceSql(); ?

Comment: Exatamente, @GOKUSSJGod.

Comment: mas isso não me retornaria a query do meu select ?

Comment: tentei aqui não dar certo chama desse forma, o Produto já e um objeto materializado com o (FirstOrDefault). não tem como passar ele como IQueryable.

Comment: Também não tenho o método ou classe (GetTable) no meu dbContext. isso é de alguma biblioteca externar ?

Comment: editei a resposta com outras informações e ajustes.

Comment: Veja que Produto já é um objeto materializado, então a chama ctx.Produto.GetModifiedMembers(Produto);  a parte **ctx.Produto** , não existirá e também não consegui chama através do  ctx.Tabela_Produtos.GetModifiedMembers(Produto); ele me retorna o erro  CS1106 C# Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: `GetModifiedMembers` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412116/linq-to-sql-logging-with-getmodifiedmembers-lookup-values é para a camada antiga `Linq To SQL` e o que foi perguntado é `Entity Framework` pelo que pude perceber!

Comment: o principio da implementação é o mesmo @VirgilioNovic. Editei a resposta com uma outra abordagem utilizando o `GetModifiedMembers`.

Comment: @MarllonNasser, a questão 1, na realidade ele tem sim uma forma de saber o que foi alterado e com base nisso o context e inteligente o suficiente para gera a query simplificada com exatamente os campos que foram alterados. vi isso no livro Entity Framework 4 a estrutura de entidades em ação página 82.

Comment: Você diz a questão 3, @GOKUSSJGod? a 1 é sobre criar `statements` "na mão" com o `Context`, não é isso?